# Javascript Function unable to get 'this' variable

Tags: javascript, html, variables

I'm starting on a small HTML5 game and it's the first one I'm doing on. At the moment, I'm creating a function that holds variables, I don't really know what it's called, I just remember how to do it from a tutorial. Anyway, I'm trying to set up some of the variables using 'this' but it doesn't seem to get a value. Here's the code that I think is causing the problem:

```
function ship() {
    this.width = 100;
    this.height = 75;
    this.drawX = gameWidth/2 - this.width/2;
    this.drawY = gameHeight + this.height;
}
```

this.drawX and Y however, seem to not get a value. Also, I'm sure that gameHeight and gameWidth have a value.

Edit: Here is the draw function and rest of the code:

```
var player = new ship();

var gameWidth  = canvasShip.width;
var gameHeight = canvasShip.height;

var sprites = new Image();
sprites.src = 'images/spriteSheet.png';

var canvasPlayer = document.getElementById('canvasShip');
var ctxPlayer = canvasPlayer.getContext('2d');

//Clear any canvas
function clearCtx(canvas) { 
    canvas.clearRect(0,0,gameWidth,gameHeight);
}

//Ship object, the player
function ship() {
    this.width = 100;
    this.height = 75;
    console.log(gameWidth,gameHeight);
    this.drawX = gameWidth/2 - this.width/2;
    this.drawY = gameHeight + this.height;
}

ship.prototype.draw = function() {
    clearCtx(ctxPlayer);
    ctxPlayer.drawImage(sprites,0,0,this.width,this.height,this.drawX,this.drawY, this.width, this.height);
}
```

Comment: How are you trying to call the function? `ship()` or `foo.ship()`?

Comment: Try to `console.log([gameWidth,gameHeight])` before `this.drawX=...` and debug what's wrong.

Comment: Passerby, the command "console.log(gameWidth,gameHeight)" give me 500 800 and Matt Ball, I'm saying var player - new ship(); then player.draw()

Comment: where's `player.draw()` defined?

Comment: You're defining the `gameWidth/Height` variables after you  create the `new ship();` instead of before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part in your code looks fishy:

```
var player = new ship();

var gameWidth  = canvasShip.width;
var gameHeight = canvasShip.height;
```

Inside the constructor of `ship()`, the values of `gameWidth` and `gameHeight` would be `undefined`.

Reversing the statements should work as expected:

```
var gameWidth  = canvasShip.width,
gameHeight = canvasShip.height,
player = new ship();
```

---

This is the way that JavaScript sees your code:

```
var gameWidth, gameHeight, player, ship;

ship = function() { ... }

player = new ship();
gameWidth = 123;
gameHeight = 456;
```

The declaration of `ship()` gets moved up in a process sometimes referred to as "[hoisting](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/2/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting)", making it more obvious why it behaves this way.

Comment: @JackDavis It works because otherwise you're trying to access something before you define it.

Comment: @JackDavis I've added some explanation in terms of how JavaScript treats your code.